# How to call a PHP function from Javascript in Wordpress

Tags: php, functions, javascript

I have a very simple plugin with a javascript file and a PHP file. I want to call the PHP file from my javascript code and get the output. The javascript functions is something like the following:

```
function img_upload(){

        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();           
        ajax.open('GET', 'http://My_Domain_Name.com/wp-content/plugins/My_Plugin/auth.php', false);
        ajax.send();

    if (ajax.status === 200) {

      console.log(ajax.responseText);

    }
```

and the PHP file which returns the results:

```
<?php
$token=Get_Token();
echo $token;
function Get_Token()
{
   //Do some stuff
   return $token;
}
?>
```

both files (auth.php and myjs.js) are in the root directory of the plugin.

```
/home/My_Username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/My_Plugin
```

If I use the domain name I can call the php file in ajax.open() and get the results, but I know this is not the right way to do that. How can I call the php file inside my javascrip code via ajax.open('path_to_php') in Wordpress properly without indicating the domain name?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

Use this sample JavaScript code:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.some-element', function(e){
    var ipc = jQuery(this).data('collection-id');
    jQuery('.some-other-element').show();

    jQuery.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: ipAjaxVar.ajaxurl,
        data: {
            collection_id: ipc,
            action: 'my_function',
        }
    }).done(function(msg) {
        // Do something when done
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

PHP (include the function in your plugin, do not use a separate file):

```
// Include the JavaScript above in your plugin
wp_enqueue_script('main', plugins_url('js/jquery.main.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '', true);

wp_localize_script('main', 'ipAjaxVar', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
));

add_action('wp_ajax_my_function', 'my_function');
```

**UPDATE:**

Add the PHP code to your main plugin file. Create a JavaScript file - `js/jquery.main.js` - and add the code above. That should do the trick.

Comment: May you please describe your codes a little more? I am newbie to plugins world. I need just a simple code. Where should I add wp_enqueue_script, wp_localize_script?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Add the PHP code to your main plugin file. Create a JavaScript file - `js/jquery.main.js` - and add the code above. That should do the trick.

Answer (score -2):

Use `plugins_url()` to get the location of `site/wp-content/plugins`:

```
ajax.open('GET', '<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>/My_Plugin/auth.php', false);
```

This will put the following HTML code in:

```
ajax.open('GET', 'http://my.domain.com/wp-content/plugins/My_Plugin/auth.php', false);
```

If your file is a full JavaScript file and not part of a template, you can make your JavaScript file in to a PHP file like so:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/javascript'); //mark this PHP file as a JS file
?>
var pluginUrl = '<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>';

ajax.open('GET', pluginUrl + '/My_Plugin/auth.php', false);
//.....
```

Save this with the name `image_upload.js.php` (or whatever you are naming it) and then just include it normally:

```
wp_enqueue_script('image_upload', plugins_url() . '/My_Plugin/image_upload.js.php');
```

Comment: As described in the question, the JavaScript is in a .js file. They can’t use PHP functions there.

Comment: Please see my edit. You can inject PHP in to a JS file just fine so long as it is saved as a PHP file and included as a JS file.

Comment: I don't want to change the structure of my files. I mean I don't want to put javascipts in php file. I think I should somehow use admin-ajax.php for this purpose but I don't know how to do that?

Comment: See my answer above.